# this.setState is not a function, react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, this

It is telling me this.setState' is undefined, but i'm not sure what I can do to make "this" refer to the proper context for setState. I don't know what else I can bind to help.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
 import axios from 'react-native-axios';

 export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     data: 50
   }
   this.apirequest = this.apirequest.bind(this);
 }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.apirequest();
  }

  apirequest() { 

    axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data.main.temp);
      this.setState({
         data: response.data.main.temp 
       })
    })
   .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use arrow function inside the `then` block to stay in the scope:

```
.then(response => {
  this.setState({
     data: response.data.main.temp 
   })
})
```

Comment: It might be worth explaining this a bit more? I see this issue a lot with beginners and they blindly use the fat arrow, without realizine about scope.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing your function by using a ES6 fat arrow function

instead of

`.then(function (response) {...`

do

`.then(response => { ...`

This works because fat arrow functions do not redefine the definition of `this`, therefore the value of `this` is still the originating context